# How to skip bytes in file read using stream

Tags: stream, io, fortran

I'm trying to read some noncontiguous fields from a fixed length data using Fortran. I would like to read (stream) from a binary file an array of 4 byte integers each separated by 6 bytes (i.e. read 4bytes, skip 6bytes, read 4bytes, skip 6bytes,...). I could use a dummy variable of size 6bytes; however, I was wondering if there was an option in the read statement to skip bytes after reading each element of the array. Thanks in advance for you help.

Eric

Comment: You just need to seek forward.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is direct access files: [Direct-access files](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features#Direct-access_files).  Here you specify the number of bytes per record in the the `OPEN` statement, then specify which record to read in your `READ` statement.  In your case the record length would be 10 bytes and you would only use the first 4 bytes of each record.

Personally I would just use a dummy variable and a format statement.  I think it would make the final code more clear and I don't think there would be any performance penalty.

Comment: Direct-access is when you want to be able to process the records in any order, not necessarily sequential.  I think that this is an unnecessary complication for this problem.   I second your recommendation to use the default sequential file access and a dummy variable.